# Check if user answers with blue thumb

Tags: botframework

I'm developing a chatbot with Microsoft Bot Framework in Node JS. Now I'm having the issue that I cannot find how to check if the user answers with the big blue thumb. Is there any possibility to check for this? So I can answer 'You're welcome' or something like that? I searched the internet for a while but couldn't find any usable answer.

Thanks in advance!
Kind regards!

Comment: Is something coming back in the sourceEvent property?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mension that it's a Messenger bot, but I think that was already clear now? Anyway,  if I create a text prompt and answer it with a thumb it fails and says "I didn't understand. Please try again". And if I console.log the response it doens't show something. So I think the thumb is not an valid input?

Comment: I have no experience with this but I think it might just return a unicode code for thumb up. Have you tried to just make your bot return the value om Activity.Text? (To see what it is.)

Comment: please share a code sample to show us how you are doing it

Comment: I just made this dialog as a test, and it still says : 'I didn't understand. Please try again.' If I answer any other emoji, it returns them correctly. bot.dialog('/test', [ (session)=>{ builder.Prompts.text(session, "What is your name?"); }, (session,result) =>{ session.send(result.response); } ]);

Comment: I fixed it! I made an global function where i check the sessions message. So it evaluates every input of a user. The blue thumb has an specific message & sticker_id. This is the response in the console: `message: { mid: 'mid.TOKEN', seq: RandomNumber, is_echo: false, attachments: [Object], sticker_id: 369239263222822 } } `This method also allows you to see if the user sends a .gif or something like that. This way you can provide an appropriate answer for (almost) everything.